# Stacking Dialogs in Android

Tags: android, dialog, stack

Is there a way to control the relative stacking of Dialogs produced by your own Activity? For instance, there are some more important Dialogs which I would like to ensure are on top and if another Dialog wants to pop up I would want it to pop *under* the important Dialogs.

Example: I want to present to the user an important dialog, Dialog A. The activity realizes that there is a dialog, Dialog B, of lesser importance to display to the user. Is it possible to specify Dialog B to be under Dialog A so that when Dialog A is cleared, Dialog B will be seen by the user?

I know that the onDismiss interface exists, but this necessarily ties Dialog A and Dialog B together. I want the Dialogs to be independent and would prefer to use a higher level abstraction like the window stack responsible for ordering the Dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no such way as far as I know.